# where to write the Navigation Component safeArgs dependencies in gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-safe-args

I started to learn navigation component library but I cannot figure out where to add the safeargs dependencies. I should add these dependencies in https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation. I tried many scenarios but none of them worked.here is my app gradle file:

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
compileSdk 32

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.yusufemirbektas.bottomnavfrags"
    minSdk 21
    targetSdk 32
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
buildFeatures {
    viewBinding true
}
}

dependencies {
def nav_version = "2.5.2"

// Java language implementation
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
// Testing Navigation
androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"
// Jetpack Compose Integration
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version"

debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.9.1'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

and here is my project gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub- 
projects/modules.
plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.1' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.1' apply false
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your project level `build.gradle` file:

```kotlin
buildscript {
    ...

    dependencies {
        ...

        classpath("androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version")
    }
}
```

And then your app `build.gradle` file:

```kotlin
plugins {
    ...

    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin")
}
...

dependencies {
    ...

    // ... Navigation
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version")
}
```